# Implement React in Phases, how possible?

Tags: reactjs

We have large platform with many features, and we are planning to migrate from standard implementation to React, and we need to know is there a way to transform our platform into react in phases instead of doing the whole platform into react and launch it? For example if we have sign in/sign up pages and functions can we launch them first in React and then the rest the of platform gradually?

your help would be highly appreciated, thank you

Comment: What is your "standard implementation" that needs to migrate, made from?

Comment: thank you Jelle. Yii2 with bootstrap.